# Is the logarithm of a martingale still a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

For example $S_t = S_0\cdot \exp(\sigma W^*_t - 0.5\sigma^2t)$ is martingale (it's a part of Black-Scholes).
Is $\ln S_t$ a martingale?

Comment: No. A strictly concave function of a martingale can't be a martingale (except the trivial case of a constant).

Comment: @ProfessorVector: same holds for strictly convex functions, correct? (i.e. $W_t$ is a martingale, but $e^{W_t}$ is not a martingale, of course...). So can we conclude that only linear functions of martingales are martingales?

Comment: @Jan Stuller Well, be careful how to formulate that. Something like "let $f$ be a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so that for any martingale $M$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$, $f(M)$ is a martingale, too, then $f$ is (affine) linear" might work (the proof is trivial and left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ln(S_t)=ln(S_0)-0.5\sigma^2 t + \sigma W^{*}_t$$

When you look at the above, you see the process $ln(S_t)$ has a drift $-0.5\sigma^2 t$, so it cannot possibly be a martingale. Just taking the expectation we see that:

$$\mathbb{E}[ln(S_t)]=ln(S_0)-0.5\sigma^2 t$$

On the other hand, when we exponentiate, the expectation is centered on the initial value (because of the mean property of lognormally distributed random variable):

$$\mathbb{E}[S_t]=\mathbb{E}[S_0e^{-0.5\sigma^2 t + \sigma W^{*}_t}]=S_0$$

So the above looks like a much more plausible Martingale candidate!

In general, intuitively, if you see a process with a (deterministic) drift, **it cannot possibly be a Martingale**, because it's future expected values will not be centered on the "current" value.