# $(f(X_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ martingale implies $f'' = 0$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I want to understand why the following statement holds:  $f \in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$. If for every martingale $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$, $(f(X_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is also a martingale, then the second derivative of $f$ is zero.

Comment: LOL. Just made a comment to that effect: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925022/is-the-logarithm-of-a-martingale-still-a-martingale#comment8102449_3925022

Comment: If $f(X_n)$ is a martingale is both a sub martingale and a super martingale, then use Jensen's inequality to see that if the latter holds then the function $f$ must be convex and concave simultaneously. Hence the only option is that it's affine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $x<y<z$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$ is such that $\lambda x+(1-\lambda z) = y$. Let $X_1$ be a random variable with $P[X_1 = x]=\lambda = 1-P[X_1=z]$. Put $X_0=y$. Then $(X_0,X_1,X_1,\ldots)$ is a martingale. By the hypothesis, $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) z) = f(y) = \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(z)$. Vary $x,z$, and $\lambda$ and you see that $f(x) = mx+b$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution, which only shows that $f'' \equiv 0$ and not that $f(x) = mx+b$.

We only consider the case where $X=B$ is a Brownian Motion. By Ito's Lemma, we obtain $$df(B_t) = f'(B_t)dB_t + \frac{1}{2}f''(B_t)dt$$
since it is a martingale, we obtain that almost surely $\int_0^tf''(B_s)ds = 0$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Since $f''$ is continuous, this implies $f''(B_t) = 0$ for every $t$, and thus $f''\equiv0$.